# How secure is this scheme?

Tags: secret-sharing, secrets-management, 3des

## Introduction of the cryptosystem

Let's say we have a system with a central server `SRV` that is considered secure (communication with this server is secured too with TLS).

Then let's say we have many clients `CLIENT` which are supposed to be secure too (their firmware is encrypted with a per-client unique, non readable key)

Finally, we have some tag `TAG` that can store some data unencrypted and only one secret item with a key of our choice. The `TAG` contains a unique identifier but this can be spoofed.

The communication between `CLIENT` and `TAG` is unsecure (can be eavesdropped). Yet, the `TAG` contains a authentication scheme that can be used to certify `CLIENT` knows the same secret key that's stored in the `TAG` and prevent reading the secret item if the authentication failed.

Authentication does not reveal the secret key.

So for a simple diagram, it looks like this:

```
           SRV
         //   \\
     CLIENT1  CLIENT2  --- TAG1
                      \__ TAG2


// double line means secure communication, simple line means insecure communication
```

I want to perform the following features:

1. A `TAG` could be enrolled on any `CLIENT`
2. The `CLIENT` learn the `TAG` and store some identifying information in its own memory and also on the `SRV`. It can store information in the `TAG` too.
3. The `CLIENT` should recognize an already enrolled `TAG` securely without connecting to the `SRV`
4. Another `CLIENT` should recognize a `TAG` that its has not enrolled by connecting to the `SRV`
5. The `CLIENT` should allow to forget an enrolled `TAG` (with or without connection the `SRV`) and when this happens, such `TAG` should not be accepted anymore on another `CLIENT`

Please notice that I can't use the `TAG`'s unique identifier because it's not unique (one can spoof such identifier either by reading the `TAG` or by emulating a `TAG`), so storing the `TAG` UID in the `CLIENT` and/or `SRV` is not safe.

Also, using a common shared secret between `CLIENT` and `SRV` to store on the `TAG` secret's area is not safe either since any tag emulator will capture such secret when it's programmed on the `TAG`'s secret key (this is done in clear).

## Proposed solution

I'm thinking of using Shamir's secret sharing `SSS` here with the number of share set to 2 and the number of part set to 3.

### Typically, the enrolling process is:

1. Read the `TAG` UID as `TagUID`
2. Read some data in the unsecure area as `KeyTag`
3. If `KeyTag` is not empty, exit enrolling
4. Pick a random `Key`
5. Use `SSS` with `Key` to make 3 parts: `KeyTag`,  `KeyClient`, `KeySrv`
6. Write `KeyClient` in `CLIENT` memory for the `TagUID`
7. Write `KeyTag` in the unsecure area of the `TAG`
8. Send (`TagUID => KeySrv`) to `SRV` for remote storage
9. Write `Key` to the `Tag` secure vault (so next authentications will require such key)
10. Store some ID/signature/HMAC/Whatever in the `TAG`'s secret area

### The `TAG` recognition process is like this:

1. Read the `TagUID` from the `TAG`
2. Read `KeyTag` from the `TAG` unsecure area
3. If there is a `KeyClient` for such `TagUID` in `CLIENT` memory,

   2.1 Compute `Key` from `SSS(KeyClient, KeyTag)`
4. Else

   3.1 Query `SRV` for `KeySrv` for such `TagUID`
   3.2 Compute `Key` from `SSS(KeySrv, KeyTag)`
5. Authenticate with `Key`
6. Read ID/signature/HMAC from the secure area, and check it's valid.

### The `TAG` forget process is:

1. Read `TagUID`
2. If connected, remove such `TagUID` from `SRV`
3. Erase `KeyTag` from the `TAG`
4. Authenticate with the `TAG` (following the previous process)
5. Erase secure area from the `TAG`
6. Erase authentication from the `TAG`
7. Remove `KeyClient` for this `TagUID` in `CLIENT` memory

This scheme seems secure from the many scenario I've thought about, yet I need some expert checking here for what I might have overlooked.

Here are the cases I've thought about:

1. When used with a tag emulator, one could intercept the random `Key` for a given `TAG` but that should not compromise the security of the other tags or other clients. That is, such emulator when used on other `CLIENT` will be detected as a valid `TAG`, yet it can't read any other `TAG` nor inpersonate them.
2. If the `CLIENT` is disconnected from the `SRV` while forgetting a `TAG`, it'll still wipe the `TAG` thus there will be no more a `KeyTag` on it and as such it can't be decoded anymore. Here the `SRV` could contain stale `TagUID, KeySrv` combination, but that should not hurt.
3. An emulator providing wrong `KeyTag` does not gain anything since computed `Key` will not pass authentication and it's not possible to read a `TAG`'s `Key` once programmed. Thus, the ID/signature/HMAC reading will not pass.
4. A attacker opening a `CLIENT` would not get any information since there is no common secure key in the `CLIENT` for all tags. At best, she could get the vault of `KeyClient` for each `TAG` but in order to gain advantage, it would also need the `KeyTag` for each `TAG`.
5. Any eavesdropping on the `CLIENT`/`SRV` communication should not reveal anything, since it's protected by TLS.

Did I miss anything ?

Comment: their firmware is encrypted with a per-client unique, non readable key - This seems like a false assumption.  Something needs to be able to read the key in order to decrypt the data, regardless if it's unique to the client or not.

Comment: Yes, the client ROM can read the key but no peripheral can (it's burnt in the efuse of such client's CPU), I'd say that reading it requires some desoldering of the chip and an X ray machine. I don't think what's protected by this system would worth such investment. I know that updating the firmware for the client is also at risk but that's not part of this question.

Comment: Let's take a step back here.  Is this discussion for a theoretical crypto system, or one that is actually intended for real world use?

Comment: It's both. I know of at least one system where the client's encrypted firmware is already considered secure enough. I thought entering in details for all parts of the system would be too much here, so I made the hypothesis the client's firmware can not be read nor can the server's software and the communication between client and server.

Comment: If this is for an actual system, I would recommend going with an approach more in line with best practices, rather than rolling your own.   Assuming that the client is secure and trusting that it will never need to be updated is dangerous.  The Shell shock bug was discovered 25 years after it was introduced.  Regarding vulnerabilities for your specific crypto system, the first thing that comes to mind is I don't see anything which would prevent an attacker from submitting bad data to SRV and creating a DoS condition.

Comment: Do you know of a similar approach using best practices for acheiving my goals?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100029/discussion-between-user52472-and-xryl669).